# how to resolve this Error: "physical file does not exist"

Tags: sas

I couldn't resolve this error where I'm specifying a path to a file. But it seems that the compiler cannot recognize it.
 Please help

[image: w to]

Comment: You need to specify the file itself as well, not just the path to the folder containing the files.  If you want to import each Excel file in a folder, update your code attempts and question.

Answer (score 3):

If SAS says the file doesn't exist then it is not there.  Not surprising as that is a really strange name for a file.

Why would you name a file `xlsx`?  That is the extension that Excel uses for workbooks.  If it actually is an Excel workbook then why would you try to read it as if it was a simple text file?

Also note that it looks like your file explorer window is not showing you the full filename. None of the files in your picture have the extension part of the filename displayed.  What is the full name for that file? Either turn on the display of the extension or use properties to see the real filename.

Comment: But if you look at the file system it is there?

Comment: Your screen shot does not appear to show the full filenames. None of the files has their extension shown.

Comment: What does not work mean?  Not found? Or do you mean your data step didn't work?  If it really is `.xmls` file (whatever that is) then that means it is probably not a simple text file.

Comment: From the explorer try 'copy as path' and paste that into SAS program.  To copy as path: <SHIFT><Right Click> to show context menu copy as path should be about halfway down.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an Excel file that way anyway, so this is using the wrong approach entirely. INFILE is for reading  in text type files, not for reading in an Excel file. Assuming you're trying to import your data, this is what you're likely looking to do this:

```
 proc import out=want datafile='c:\users\pi\Documents\xlsx.xlsx' dbms=xlsx replace; run;
```

PLEASE do not post code and log as images in the future.  It makes it harder to help you and answer your question when we first have to type out your code or data.